# Where does pip and conda keep the list of installed packages so that they know who installed what?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I did some `pip install` in my `conda` environment, and it seems that both `conda` and `pip` follow the python convention, by installing packages into the `site-packages` folder.

When I use `pip list` and `conda list`, it seems they did a nice book keeping of who installed which packages. Question is, where are those two installation lists stored, on Linux?

Comment: Maybe follow the source code for [pip list](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/list.py).

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In case of `pip list`, the [pkg_resources](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-workingset-methods) library is used to access resource files for Python Libraries.

For this, a [Working Set](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#workingset-objects) access the active distributions. From the docs, a working set

> represents the distributions that are currently active on sys.path.

Thus, when calling an instance of `WorkingSet`, by default it will search for modules located on `sys.path`.

For example, when I run `sys.path`

```
['/opt/conda/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions'
]
```

These are the paths that will be used to search for installed packages. An example follows

```
import pkg_resources

# Define working set
working_set = pkg_resources.working_set

# Package, version and location 
[d for d in working_set]
>>>
[zipp 3.1.0 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 zict 2.0.0 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
...,
attrs 19.3.0 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 async-generator 1.10 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages),
 alembic 1.4.2 (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages)]
```

Comment: to complement this answer, I found that in the above mentioned folders, `pip list` looks for a file named like `package_name.egg-info`, with a `Version` field in it, OR, a folder named like `package_name-x.y.z.dist-info`, with a file named `METAFILE` in it.

Comment: `conda list` searches for a legit `.json` file for each package in `<CONDA_PREFIX>/conda-meta` folder